# nginx how to override/add single mime-type

Tags: nginx, mime-type

I tried to add markdown rendering by putting

`types {  text/markdown md; }`

into `server` section, but then index.html stopped to be rendered all of a sudden. I can explain this only if `types` overrides the whole set of mime types for this section.

So, is there a way to just add mime-type for Markdown without touching anything else?

Comment: Found the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789494/extending-default-nginx-mime-types-file

Answer (score 3):

Add it in a mime.types file and include it from the http stanza as demonstrated in:

http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample

Adding in the line:

```
text/markdown  md;
```

to the mime.types file

Comment: I'd like to avoid shipping custom `mime.type` files for every server configuration. Is there a way to make mime overrides/additions with nginx config alone?

Comment: As far as overrides for any existing extensions already mapped in the `mime.type` file, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629930/force-nginx-to-send-specific-content-type. You need do something like this: `location ~* \.js$ {
  types { }
  default_type "text/javascript; charset=utf-8";
}`

Comment: Check out [extending default nginx mime.types file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20566966/102675)